# find average value from array

Tags: c++, arrays, average

for some reason, I am getting a very weird negative nuber as my average for my program, here is my code:

```
int sum, avg;
int size;
size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
sum = 0;
avg = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    sum += array[i];
}
avg = sum / size
```

My output is: -6.84941e+061

Comment: `std::accumulate` and a division will do this without the need to write your own loop.

Comment: Show us how you declare your array and what its contents are.

Comment: Or better yet, show a compilable example inside a `main` function which demonstrates the output you're getting.

Comment: Tell us what the nature of the *data* is. Are they large numbers, small numbers, a large amount of small/large numbers, etc? What is the size of an `int` on your system? does the partial sum ever exceed INT_MAX before the division? Have you considered **debugging** this?

Comment: Does your array contain a lot of negative numbers?

Comment: no negative numbers, they contain double digit numbers. so ex: 40.20

Comment: Your code shows avg is type int.  How does that print a floating point value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(int i = 1; i < size; i++){
       //^^should be 0
   sum += array[i];
}
avg = sum / size; //pay attention to truncation when doing integer division
```

you should pay attention to truncation when divide integers. For example, `10/20 = 0` in integer division.
meanwhile, you need to start from 0 when computing sum.

Your code should look like the following:

```
 //the average may not necessarily be integer
 float avg = 0.0;  //or double for higher precision
 for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
 {
     sum += array[i];
 }
 avg = ((float)sum)/size; //or cast sum to double before division
```

Comment: thank you, just noticed that, but that didnt fix it...

Comment: what about double? because that is what I am using.

Comment: @user12074577 double is also OK. but you still need to pay attention to integer truncation is sum is integer. only declare avg double is not enough

Comment: Even if it was integer truncation that still shouldn't be the cause of the output.

Comment: @user12074577 how did you fill values into your array?

Comment: @tacp i filled them using an ifstream from a text file. You were helping me a bit ago with a min version of this. I got the min, max to work. Avg of the data is causing me the issues.

Comment: @user12074577 Update your post showing us the code where you do that.

Comment: @user12074577 your current average (with my updates) looks OK, if you still see strange values, there must be some other places that your array values have been changed or not filled in correctly.

Comment: @tacp could this be the reason?: "warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data"

Comment: @user12074577 you will lose data precision by converting from double to int. But that is unlikely to be the cause of strange value. Could you update your codes in post?

Comment: never mind i figured it out! It was something with my input not throwing the right numbers in.

Comment: @user12074577 great, that justifies our guess.